# cgeev sovle Non Hermitain matrix is incorrect

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Recently I want to reproduce the Fig.1(a) of [Edge States and Topological Invariants of Non-Hermitian Systems](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.121.086803).I used cgeev to solve eigenvalue of non-Hermitian Hamiltonian matrices，I found the solution become wired.
Here is my Fortran code,the result to Fig1.(a) correspond the *abs.dat*.

```
    module pub
    implicit none
    complex,parameter::im = (0.0,1.0)
    real,parameter::pi = 3.1415926535
    integer xn,N,en,kn
    parameter(xn = 100,N = xn*2,en = 100)
    complex Ham(N,N)
    real t1,t2,t3,gam
    !-----------------
    integer::lda = N
    integer,parameter::lwmax=2*N + N**2
    complex,allocatable::w(:)   ! store eigenvalues
    complex,allocatable::work(:)
    real,allocatable::rwork(:)
    integer lwork       
    integer info
    integer LDVL, LDVR
    parameter(LDVL = N, LDVR = N )
    complex VL( LDVL, N ), VR( LDVR, N )
    end module pub
!=====================================================
    program sol
    use pub
    ! Physics memory allocate 
    allocate(w(N))
    allocate(work(lwmax))
    allocate(rwork(2*N))
    !-----------------
    t2 = 1.0
    t3 = 0.0
    gam = 3.0/4.0
    call band()
    end program sol
!======================================================
    subroutine band()
    use pub
    integer m1,i
    open(11,file="real.dat")
    open(12,file="imag.dat")
    open(13,file="abs.dat")
    do m1 = -en,en
        t1 = 3.0*m1/en
        call matset()
        call eigsol()
        write(11,999)t1,(real(w(i)),i = 1,N)
        write(12,999)t1,(aimag(w(i)),i = 1,N)
        write(13,999)t1,(abs(w(i)),i = 1,N)
    end do
    close(11)
    close(12)
    close(13)
999 format(201f11.6)
    end subroutine band
!======================================================
    subroutine matset()
    use pub
    real kx
    complex sx(2,2),sy(2,2),sz(2,2)
    integer k,m1,m2
    sx(1,2) = 1.0
    sx(2,1) = 1.0
    sy(1,2) = -im
    sy(2,1) = im
    sz(1,1) = 1.0
    sz(2,2) = -1.0
    !--------
    Ham = 0.0
    do k = 0,xn-1
        if(k == 0)then
            do m1 = 1,2
                do m2 = 1,2
                    ham(m1,m2) = t1*sx(m1,m2) + im*gam/2.0*sy(m1,m2)
                    ham(m1,m2 + 2) = (t2 + t3)/2.0*sx(m1,m2) - im*(t2 - t3)/2.0*sy(m1,m2)  
                end do
            end do
        elseif(k == xn-1)then
            do m1 = 1,2
                do m2 = 1,2
                    ham(k*2 + m1,k*2 + m2) = t1*sx(m1,m2) + im*gam/2.0*sy(m1,m2)
                    ham(k*2 + m1,k*2 + m2 - 2) = (t2 + t3)/2.0*sx(m1,m2) + im*(t2 - t3)/2.0*sy(m1,m2)  
                end do
            end do
        else
            do m1 = 1,2
                do m2 = 1,2
                    ham(k*2 + m1,k*2 + m2) = t1*sx(m1,m2) + im*gam/2.0*sy(m1,m2)
                    !   right hopping
                    ham(k*2 + m1,k*2 + m2 + 2) = (t2 + t3)/2.0*sx(m1,m2) - im*(t2 - t3)/2.0*sy(m1,m2)
                    !   left hopping
                    ham(k*2 + m1,k*2 + m2 - 2) = (t2 + t3)/2.0*sx(m1,m2) + im*(t2 - t3)/2.0*sy(m1,m2)  
                end do
            end do
        end if
    end do
    return 
    end subroutine matset
!==============================================================================
    subroutine eigsol()
    use pub
!       Query the optimal workspace.
    LWORK = -1
    CALL cgeev( 'Vectors', 'Vectors', N, Ham, LDA, W, VL, LDVL, VR, LDVR, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO)
    LWORK = MIN( LWMAX, INT( WORK( 1 ) ) )
!     Solve eigenproblem.
    CALL cgeev( 'Vectors', 'Vectors', N, Ham, LDA, W, VL, LDVL,VR, LDVR, WORK, LWORK, RWORK, INFO)
!     Check for convergence.
    IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
        WRITE(*,*)'The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.'
        STOP
    END IF
    ! open(120,file="eigval.dat")
    ! do m = 1,N
    !     write(120,*)m,w(m)
    ! end do
    ! close(120)
    return
    end subroutine eigsol
```

If I used wrong function from Lapack or my code isn't correct.

I use intel fortran,complie command is

*ifort -mkl file.f90 -o a.out

Run program ./a.out&*

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You will have to show us the results of your code.

Comment: OK, I've compiled and run your program. It produces some output files. How do I check whether these are "wired" or not? I see lots of stars which probably means you've screwed up a format somewhere, not providing enough space for what you want to output, but is there anything else I should be looking for? And please always use Implicit None - and routines in modules is much better as well.

Comment: My output data file don't have stars,I think format of data should be correct. Within the code *(999 format(201f11.6)) *  set the correct data formation

Comment: -2.970000**************************** and lots more stars (with a few other numbers) is what I see in abs.dat.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have an lots stars in my results

Comment: Same for me on Mac + gfortran-9.3 (i.e., ******* appears in the .dat files). These stars appear somewhat later in the output files. Changing `write(11,999)` to `write(11,*)` (and similar for units 12 and 13) gives all the data, but the values go to infinity very quickly. Compiling with "gfortran -O2 -fcheck=all -Wall" gives a lot of messages like "On entry to CGEBAL, parameter number  3 had an illegal value" etc, which might give some clue...?

Comment: Hmmm, I used -fcheck=all but didn't see that. Sounds like an uninitialised variable somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Not tested, but `WORK` is allocated of size 2N+N*N, then a workspace query is performed, then the resulting optimal LWORK is provided to CGEEV(). Could you try to deallocate / allocate WORK to the correct size? See the source of CGEEV() : as vectors are required, it performs a workspace query to `CTREVC3`, that returns n + 2*n*nb. As a result, the optimal workspace is likely 2*n+2*n*n, larger than the allocated space. It could induce an undefined behavior.

Comment: I copy this [example](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/cgeev_ex.f.htm),just replaced the A to mine matrix,but the answer isn't correct too.

Comment: Sorry, my fault : I did not see the `LWORK = MIN( LWMAX, INT( WORK( 1 ) ) )`, that avoids the problem.